# Insert Data Into Wordpress Database Custom Table From Custom Form

Tags: sql, wordpress, forms

[Insert data into Wordpress database table from a custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582193/insert-data-into-wordpress-database-table-from-custom-form/33984534?noredirect=1#comment55725109_33984534)

I have worked with your example but I have a problem. I have error on the start. I get this message:

> WordPress database error: [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (prowebex_barbara.barbara_schedule, CONSTRAINT
>   barbara_schedule_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (day_id) REFERENCES barbara_days
>   (id_day))]

```
INSERT INTO barbara_schedule (id, challenger, challenged,
 date_match, day_id, term_start, term_end) VALUES ('', 'gfdgdfgdfg', 'gdfgfdgdf', '2015-11-30', '', '23:00', '00:59');
```

Data Submitted

Can you tell me how can I change this. I have already, truncate tables,delete both tables. I don't know what to do.

```
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
           global $wpdb;

           $id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['id']);
           $challenger = sanitize_text_field($_POST['challenger']);
           $challenged = sanitize_text_field($_POST['challenged']);
           $date_match = sanitize_text_field($_POST['date_match']);
           $day = sanitize_text_field($_POST['day_id']);
           $term_start = sanitize_text_field($_POST['term_start']);
           $term_end = sanitize_text_field($_POST['term_end']);

           $table_name = $wpdb->prowebex_barbara.barbara_schedule;

           $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
               'id' => $id,
               'challenger' => $challenger,
               'challenged' => $challenged,
               'date_match' => $date_match,
               'day_id' => $day,
               'term_start' => $term_start,
               'term_end' => $term_end,
           ),
               array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
           );
           $msg = "Data Submited";
           echo $msg;
       }?>

        <form action="" method="post" id="subForm">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="iiihuu-iiihuu" placeholder="" />
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="challenger" id="iiihuu-iiihuu" placeholder="Izazivač" />
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="challenged" id="iiihuu-iiihuu" placeholder="Izazvani" />
                <br>
                <input type="date" name="date_match" id="iiihuu-iiihuu" placeholder="Datum" />
                <br>
                <select>
                       <option>I don't know how to do this</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="time" name="term_start" id="iiihuu-iiihuu" placeholder="Termin od" />
                <br>
                <input type="time" name="term_end" id="iiihuu-iiihuu" placeholder="Termin do" />
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Spasi" class ="submit_button" id="formSubmit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors look like that the custom tables actually have relationship with each other, not sure how the database structure is, but it looks like in order to create a record in barbara_schedule you will have to also create a record in barbara_days.

**So in order to just check if this is the case you should pass a fake day_id. So replace $_POST['day_id'] with an existing day_id that already exists in the barbara_days table.**

But if thats not the case, then here is a quick thought, do you have a require statement on the top of this file?
Usually this is needed in order to make an insert on custom tables besides the meta table.

```
require_once('LINK-TO/wp-load.php');
```

Secondly i am not sure, what this outputs

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prowebex_barbara.barbara_schedule;
```

but just in case, try to hardcode the table name like this

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."table-name"
```